# how to automatically upload a video to YouTube using JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, youtube-api

How to Upload a video to YouTube using java technology (JSP)using YouTube API and Google API. Please give me the full details of how to upload because I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously here you will have to deal with the [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/)

[This page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) contains a java example to upload a video.

Comment: where i need to put this json file in webapp..Please show me how the folder looks. I mean parent and child mehthod in this webapp.Did I need to maintain the any .jar file for this?

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation there is a sample of how to do that:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

What kind of application are you developing?
May be the best approach to you is to use YouTube Direct Lite:

https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/